# Domain of $\sqrt{x}$ function when solving $x^2 - 2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I've been going through this solution and got stuck on explaining myself why  $x^2 = 2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2} =  \sqrt{2}\Rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt2$.  Domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is $[0,\infty)$. How taking square root both sides give $\pm \sqrt{2}$ ?

[image: quadratic equation]

Comment: That is because the author is not "taking the square root" to give the solution, but is saying that if two real numbers have the same square, then they are either equal or opposite

Comment: Don't confuse $\sqrt{\pm x^2}$ and $\pm\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @DIdier_ that makes more sense as it refers to only the $f(x)=x^2$ function and doesn't require to think of taking the square root. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is not clear to you?

In general $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

So your equation is equivalent to $|x| = \sqrt{2}$
And from that last equation you find the two roots
$x=-\sqrt{2}$ and $x=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Ohk thanks peter im a bit rusty on these. I was messing with compositions: $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ then $g(f(x)) = \sqrt{x^2}$. domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$ and range is $[0,\infty)$. This matches with the domain and range of $|x|$ so replacing $\sqrt{x^2}$ with $|x|$ makes sense. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 3):

I think whoever wrote the text was referring to the real-valued identity $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$, hence $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt2\Leftrightarrow \lvert x\rvert=\sqrt2\Leftrightarrow x=\sqrt2\lor x=-\sqrt2.$

Personally, I'm something of a fan of $$x^2-2=0\Leftrightarrow (x+\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2)=0\Leftrightarrow x-\sqrt2=0\lor x+\sqrt2=0.$$

Comment: I too like this straight simple factoring! Thanks Gae :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct concepts at play here. $\sqrt{x}$ is a *function* denoting the nonnegative square root of $x$. However, the general solution to $a^2 = b^2$ is $a = \pm b$. So $\sqrt{25}=5$, but if $x^2=25$ then $x=\pm5$. As Gae. S. has already mentioned, the easiest way to see that $a^2=b^2 \iff a= \pm b$ is through factorisation:
\begin{align}
&a^2=b^2 \\
\iff&a^2-b^2=0 \\
\iff&(a+b)(a-b)=0 \\
\iff&a=-b \text{ or } a=b \, .
\end{align}
So, in your example, we have $x^2=(\sqrt{2})^2 \iff x=\pm\sqrt{2}$.